# Promise.onSuccess called immediately

Tags: swift, promise, future

I'm using [BrightFutures](https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures) and when I run the following code, `sequence().onComplete` and `sequence().onSuccess` is called before the geoCoder completionHandler is finished. Can you help me please to get this running?

```
self.uploadContentSequence = [Future<Future<Void, NoError>, NoError>]();

for post in posts {
     self.uploadContentSequence.append(future(self.preparePostUpload(post)))
}

self.uploadContentSequence.sequence().onComplete { (_) -> Void in
    print("onComplete")
}.onSuccess { (_) -> Void in
    print("onSuccess")
}.onFailure { (_) -> Void in
    print("onFailure")
}

[...]

func preparePostUpload(post: Post) -> Future<Void, NoError> {
    let promise = Promise<Void, NoError>()

    [...]

    let postLocation = CLLocation(latitude: Double(post.lat!), longitude: Double(post.lng!))
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder();
    let countryCode = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as! String
    post.country = countryCode
    geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(postLocation, completionHandler: { (placemarks, locError) -> Void in
        [...]
        promise.success()
    });

    return promise.future
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As phimage pointed out in this issue: https://github.com/Thomvis/BrightFutures/issues/111 I was wrapping the future with a completed future.